# How can I consolidate data between 2 different Workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba, consolidation

I need to consolidate 2 students’ registrations between different workbooks (holding and subsidiary). So when I click the button “Generate Graphic”, the data are consolidated in the sheet “Total” and then, the number of courses (Excel, Word, Access…) are counted and the graphic is generated in the sheet “Graphic”. The first test is ok, but when I click again, the list is increasing with the same data of the subsidiary’s workbook. There’s something in the code I need to change but I don’t know what. 
Could you help me?
My code is:

```
Sub GerarGrafico()
Dim k As Long

'copying data of the “Course Booking” Sheet

Sheets("Course Booking").Select
Range("A1").Select
linini = 2
'Select the last row
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
linfin = Selection.Row
'Select the last column
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
colfin = Selection.Column
Range(Cells(linini, 1), Cells(linfin, colfin)).Select
Selection.Copy
```

‘copying data in the sheet "Total"

```
Sheets("Total").Select
Cells(linini, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

‘Copying data of the  “reserva filial.xlsm”
caminho = ThisWorkbook.Path
Workbooks.Open caminho & "\" & "reserva filial.xlsm"

'copying data
Range("A1").Select
linini2 = 2
'Select the last row
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
linfin2 = Selection.Row
'Select the last column
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
colfin2 = Selection.Column
Range(Cells(linini2, 1), Cells(linfin2, colfin2)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Trabalho_Felipe Granado_v8.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Total").Select

'Select the last row with value
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    k = ActiveCell.Row + 1

Cells(k, 1).Activate


Application.Windows("reserva filial.xlsm").Visible = False

'pasting data "reserva filial.xlsm" in the sheet "Total"

ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

   Columns.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of the code navigates to the end of the data in the sheet

```
'Select the last row with value
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    k = ActiveCell.Row + 1

Cells(k, 1).Activate
```

Then you paste in `"reserva filial.xlsm"` data.

It works fine on the first pass, but the second time you run the code, you (correctly) paste in the first workbook data, LEAVING THE SECOND WORKBOOK DATA BENEATH IT, navigate to the end of the data, and repaste in the second workbook data.

Depending on how your Excel project fits together you might wish to clear the entire contents of `Sheets("Total")` or a subset of it using the `.ClearContents` method.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. You're right

I've put this code in the beggining:

    Dim region As Range
    Set region = Sheets("Total").Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion
    region.ClearContents

And it works fine. So every click, I need to clear all and paste the current or new students' list.

Thanks again

Comment: Great, glad you got it working. From a pure VBA code standpoint that works well. 

However, I'd advise thinking about how your Excel project could evolve in future.  If I recall correctly `.CurrentRegion` selects everything around a cell until it hits blank rows and BLANK COLUMNS.  So if you ever added some analysis to an adjacent column in the "Total" sheet, that would get deleted too.

That might be a totally irrelevant user case, but I thought I'd mention it just in case.  If all else fails, you can just add a note to the sheet saying to leave blank cols/rows!

Answer (score 0):

It works as the Ctrl + Shift + Down (arrow) and Ctrl + Shift + Right (arrow) in Excel. For now it's ok and it will be used only as a list. I really appreciatte your advise. I am a new VBA and Stack Overflow user, and this community is very useful because all of your contribution.